# Why Azure API Management caching prefixes cache keys with a number?

Tags: azure, caching, azure-api-management

While using Azure API Management caching (Internal or External) with out of the box caching policy or custom caching policy, APIM is adding a number to start of the cache key.

For Example: 2_{{cache-key}}, 3_{{cache-key}}

Is there a reason for this behavior?

Comment: Key gets generated with `"cacheKey": "{apimName}.{apiId};{revision};{backendurl with all query parameters}"` format